# How to add a screen sharing feature on a video call of Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I implemented a video call using Twilio by `react` as **frontend** and `Ruby on Rails` as **backend**.
now I wanna add **screen-sharing** on that.
Have I to change my backend code?
How to add a **screen-sharing feature** on a video call?
When I **enable** screen sharing in video calling, does my call change to an **audio call** automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't believe you need to change your back end code for this. For the front end, I would recommend checking out this blog post: [Screen Sharing with JavaScript and Twilio Programmable Video](https://www.twilio.com/blog/screen-sharing-javascript-twilio-programmable-video) (the back end for this is Python, but it shouldn't matter).

Comment: is there a way to show both screen sharing and self video to the remote participants?

Comment: Yes, the screen share and the local participant video are two different tracks that you can add to the room.